# is it possible to get the env from strip Apollo

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using strip [Apollo](https://github.com/apolloconfig/apollo) as the configuration center, now I want to use the env to process different logic this is the local `/opt/settings/server.properites` config:

```
> cat /opt/settings/server.properties
  apollo.meta=http://localhost:8080
  env=DEV
```

then I use this java client code to get the env:

```
Config config = ConfigService.getAppConfig();
String env = config.getProperty("env","default");
```

this code always get default value, what I expect value is DEV. is it possible to get the env value?